# jquery version error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, .net

In my web page, I am tryin to use both "kwick" and "cycle" jquery plug-ins. When I use one of them (does not matter which one) it is running properly. But when I try to use both, it gives an JS runtime error.

This is how I am using them :

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.6.4.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="kwick/moo1.2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="kwick/myKwcik.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="Scripts/TniyJs.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://cloud.github.com/downloads/malsup/cycle/jquery.cycle.all.latest.js"
    type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.slideshow').cycle({
            fx: 'fade', // choose your transition type, ex: fade, scrollUp, shuffle, etc...
            speed:       1500,  // speed of the transition (any valid fx speed value) 
            delay:       500,
        });
    });
</script>
```

When I use it like above(in my question) it does not give any error, my 'cycle plug-in' works but 'kwick' does not.

When I move down the "jquery-1.6.4.min.js" to last tag (to the end of the script tags) it throws me the error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'cycle'

when I disable "jquery 1.5" then : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'ready'

Please help me If you know the problem or solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this `src="kwick/myKwcik.js"` a typo in your question? If that script is missing it would explain the error.

Comment: Does IE finally support trailing commas in objects? `{delay: 500,}`

Comment: No, trailing commas are still wrong in IE.

Comment: myKwick.js is a ready plugin, but I do not think it is because of it. 

When I move down the "jquery-1.6.4.min.js" to last tag (to the end of the script tags) it throws me the error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'cycle'

when I disable "jquery 1.5" then : Microsoft JScript runtime error: Object doesn't support property or method 'ready'

And when I use it like above(in my question) it does not gives any error, my cycle plug in works but kwick does not.

Comment: You can't expect to use two versions of jQuery in the same document without having all sorts of problems; it's a terrible idea and you should figure out a better set of plugins to use. Those are both fairly old versions of the library anyway - the current version is 1.7.  Relying on plugins that nobody bothers to maintain is a mistake.

Comment: Good grief are you also using MooTools?  Making web sites work is not a process merely of finding random plugins and dropping them onto your pages.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

sounds like a Mootools & jQuery conflict

http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries

```
var $j = jQuery.noConflict();

// Use jQuery via $j(...)
$j(document).ready(function(){
    $j('.slideshow').cycle({
        fx: 'fade', 
        speed: 1500,  
        delay: 500
    });
});
```

you do not need two versions of jQuery. just reference this latest version on Google's CDN https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js
and Mootools:
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/mootools/1.4.1/mootools-yui-compressed.js

**Edit**: If you only include Mootools for kwicks you might want to consider using Kwicks for jQuery. http://www.jeremymartin.name/projects.php?project=kwicks that saves you the loading of an extra library/resource

Comment: It's a MooTools and jQuery and jQuery conflict :-)